# Set header id attribute from content with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using JavaScript what’s the simplest way to set a headers id from it’s content and swap spaces for hyphens and make lowercase.

For example, if header is:

```
<h1>Header one content</h1>
```

how can we change that to:

```
<h1 id="header-one-content">Header one content</h1>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way, iterating through all H1 tags and performing the operation:

```
$("h1").each(function() {
    var hyphenated = $(this).text().replace(/\s/g,'-');
    $(this).attr('id',hyphenated);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since jQuery is not really needed

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
for (var i=0, h1; h1 =  tags[i]; i++) {
  h1.id = h1.innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-");
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, since the question asks for the simplest (no jQuery needed), however, one line is incorrect: it should be h1.id = h1.innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "-");

Comment: `"hello you".replace(" ", "-")` outputs `"hello-you"`. The replace  method on strings takes a RegExp or a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned jQuery in your tags I assume you welcome it, so:

```
jQuery("h1:first").attr("id", "header-one-content");
```

**Updated**: Sorry, didn't read the question carefully enough.. Here's an update:

From the jQuery website:

**Example: Sets id for divs based on the position in the page.** (edited)

```
<h1>Heading One</h1>
<h1>Heading Two</h1>
<h1>Heading Three</h1>
```

Javascript:

```
$("h1").attr("id", function (arr) {
    return "header-" + arr;
});
```

Results in:

```
<h1 id="header-0">Heading One</h1>
<h1 id="header-1">Heading Two</h1>
<h1 id="header-2">Heading Three</h1>
```

More info: [jQuery.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: I think the "header-one-content" should be fetched progrmatacally.

Comment: @Gunner, ah programatically.. Posted an example from the jQuery websites which does this with divs.

Comment: Don't just post examples, there's a lot of noise in your answer, why would you include css as part of this answer?

Answer (score 0):

using JQuery:

```
var inner = jQuery("h1:first").html();
inner.replace(" ", "-");
jQuery("h1:first").attr("id", inner);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript:

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]; 
//it returns a array of h1 tags. For this example I only obtain the first position.
//you can change the index of the array to obtain your 'h1'. It depends on the position. You also can to cover the array by a for loop.

title.id = title.innerHTML.replace(/ /g, "-").toLowerCase()
//The /g operator is to define a global replace.
```